# Printing an array of numbers into multiple columns

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplotstable

I have 100 numbers and I want to print the numbers in multiple columns in one page like:

```
1 11 21........91
2 12 22........92
3 13 23........93
4 14 24........94
5 15 25........95
6 16 26........96
7 17 27........97 
.................
.................
10 20 30 ..... 100
```

To be more precise, say, I want to print my data as {10 rows * 10 column} in one page. My data is stored in a .csv file. and the format in which data is stored is like:

```
4.00E+00
5.00E+00
4.00E+00
5.00E+00
4.00E+00
6.00E+00
4.00E+00
1.00E+01
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
5.00E+00
4.00E+00
7.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
5.00E+00
4.00E+00
5.00E+00
4.00E+00
6.00E+00
5.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
6.00E+00
4.00E+00
5.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
9.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
5.00E+00
5.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
5.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
6.00E+00
5.00E+00
4.00E+00
1.10E+01
5.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
6.00E+00
5.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
5.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
6.00E+00
5.00E+00
7.00E+00
5.00E+00
5.00E+00
4.00E+00
5.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
5.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
6.00E+00
4.00E+00
7.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
8.00E+00
1.20E+01
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
8.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
6.00E+00
8.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
6.00E+00
5.00E+00
6.00E+00
5.00E+00
5.00E+00
9.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
5.00E+00
5.00E+00
4.00E+00
8.00E+00
4.00E+00
1.50E+01
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
6.00E+00
4.00E+00
```

. i have tried using pgfplotstable but i cant break the data into multiple columns. I am getting only single column.

the code i used is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{longtable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11} 
\pgfplotstableread[col sep = comma]{x_values.csv}\mydata

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[
  col sep=comma,
    ]{x_values.csv}{\fionasData}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    every head row/.style={output empty row},
    begin table=\begin{longtable},
  end table=\end{longtable},
]{\fionasData}

\end{document}
```

can anyone give any suggestion?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: please show what your input csv looks like, is it already in  6 columns. You say you want the output in 6 columns but give no indication of the input, and show a table of numbers in 3 columns which does not appear to fit the question description at all.

Comment: hi David, i have updated my query. please have a look. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `readarray` package expects space separated data (I need to change that feature).  But since your data in the file is provided single column, there are no commas in the csv file, and space/line separation is sufficient to parse the data.

EDITED to center the "table".

This uses an input file Book1.csv of the format specified:

```
1
2
3
...
98
99
100
```

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{readarray,ifthen}
\newcounter{rowindex}
\newcounter{colindex}
\begin{document}
\def\mycols{10}
\readdef{Book1.csv}{\mydata}
In this file there were \nrows\ row(s) and \ncols\ column(s) of data

I will read it into an array of \mycols\ columns.
\readArrayij{\mydata}{data}{\mycols}

There are \dataCELLS\ cells in the array, made up of
\dataROWS\ rows and \dataCOLS\ columns.

And here is the table, centered

\begin{center}
\whiledo{\therowindex<\mycols}{%
  \stepcounter{rowindex}%
  \setcounter{colindex}{0}%
  \whiledo{\thecolindex<\dataCOLS}{%
    \stepcounter{colindex}%
%    \arrayij{data}{\thecolindex}{\therowindex}\ % <--- Add desired seperator
    \makebox[.7cm][r]{\arrayij{data}{\thecolindex}{\therowindex}}% or use Fixed width
  }\par
}
\end{center}
For comparison, here are the margin delimiters\par
\noindent\hrulefill
\end{document}
```

The line with `\arrayij` can use a separator or a box for the data cell; I use a box.

[image]

---

If one didn't want the extra vertical space of the `center` environment...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{readarray,ifthen}
\newcounter{rowindex}
\newcounter{colindex}
\begin{document}
\def\mycols{10}
\readdef{Book1.csv}{\mydata}
In this file there were \nrows\ row(s) and \ncols\ column(s) of data

I will read it into an array of \mycols\ columns.
\readArrayij{\mydata}{data}{\mycols}

There are \dataCELLS\ cells in the array, made up of
\dataROWS\ rows and \dataCOLS\ columns.

And here is the table, centered

{\parindent0pt\relax
\centering
\whiledo{\therowindex<\mycols}{%
  \stepcounter{rowindex}%
  \setcounter{colindex}{0}%
  \whiledo{\thecolindex<\dataCOLS}{%
    \stepcounter{colindex}%
%    \arrayij{data}{\thecolindex}{\therowindex}\ % <--- Add desired seperator
    \makebox[.7cm][r]{\arrayij{data}{\thecolindex}{\therowindex}}% or use Fixed width
  }\par
}
\par}
For comparison, here are the margin delimiters\par
\noindent\hrulefill
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: u are an absolute genius! I have been looking for these for the past 5 hours. gone through many websites and documents! thank u so much. but i last thing, i just want to print integers rather than the exponential forms. how can i do that?

Comment: @SakilChowdhury I don't know how to automatically convert exponential to integer form (in LaTeX), but if you can tell me with absolute certainty that it will always be e8.2 format, for example, I could perhaps write a quick conversion routine.  Is there the possibility for negative data?

Comment: nope. the data will be always positive and integer. thank u so mcuh @steven

Comment: @SakilChowdhury  But will it always be `x.xxE+xx`? as opposed to `x.xxxxE+xx`...

Comment: yap. u are right. @steven

Comment: @SakilChowdhury Please give me some time to develop a routine for it.

Comment: I really appreciate your kindness and help. I am really amazed. thank u. I have solved it. actually, i changed the way python saves data in my .csv file. perviously i stored it in exp format. now i have changed it to int format. and now the table looks good. except only one prob, the table is on the right side of the page. i need the data at the center of the page. i tried to replace [r] with [c] in your code but its not working.

Comment: @SakilChowdhury  I am glad the exponential/integer problem is solved.  Do you still want columns right aligned, but the whole table centered?

Comment: i need to table to be at the center of the page so that it looks good for my report.

Comment: @SakilChowdhury Please see revision.  If you didn't mind vertical space above/below the table, you could use `\begin{center}\whiledo{...}\end{center}`

Comment: got it. u are awesome @steven. thanks a lot dear.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `select equal part entry of` for this job.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{longtable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{x_values.txt}
4.00E+00
5.00E+00
4.00E+00
5.00E+00
4.00E+00
6.00E+00
4.00E+00
1.00E+01
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
5.00E+00
4.00E+00
7.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
5.00E+00
4.00E+00
5.00E+00
4.00E+00
6.00E+00
5.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
6.00E+00
4.00E+00
5.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
9.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
5.00E+00
5.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
5.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
6.00E+00
5.00E+00
4.00E+00
1.10E+01
5.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
6.00E+00
5.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
5.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
6.00E+00
5.00E+00
7.00E+00
5.00E+00
5.00E+00
4.00E+00
5.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
5.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
6.00E+00
4.00E+00
7.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
8.00E+00
1.20E+01
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
8.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
6.00E+00
8.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
6.00E+00
5.00E+00
6.00E+00
5.00E+00
5.00E+00
9.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
5.00E+00
5.00E+00
4.00E+00
8.00E+00
4.00E+00
1.50E+01
4.00E+00
4.00E+00
6.00E+00
4.00E+00
\end{filecontents*}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep = space]{x_values.txt}\mydata

\textheight=2cm
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    header=false,
    columns={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    display columns/0/.style={select equal part entry of={0}{10}},
    display columns/1/.style={select equal part entry of={1}{10}},
    display columns/2/.style={select equal part entry of={2}{10}},
    display columns/3/.style={select equal part entry of={3}{10}},
    display columns/4/.style={select equal part entry of={4}{10}},
    display columns/5/.style={select equal part entry of={5}{10}},
    display columns/6/.style={select equal part entry of={6}{10}},
    display columns/7/.style={select equal part entry of={7}{10}},
    display columns/8/.style={select equal part entry of={8}{10}},
    display columns/9/.style={select equal part entry of={9}{10}},
    every head row/.style={output empty row},
    begin table=\begin{longtable},
  end table=\end{longtable},
]{\mydata}

\end{document}
```

Comment: hi, thank u so much for your answer. i have updated the question again to clarify my prob. please have a look. thank u so much.

Comment: hi, thank u for replying. actually, i am trying to modify the code but i cant make it work as i would like to.  i have changed the code as :    ` columns={0},  %i have only one column in my csv file
    display columns/0/.style={select equal part entry of={0}},   ` but this is not working. can u plz suggest.

Comment: please see the question. i have added the data there just now. although i could not put all of them. I have 10000 points in my csv file. and I want to print first 100 of them in my report.

Comment: @SakilChowdhury Please see the update.

Comment: thank u so much. I have got what i was looking for. thank u so much for your time and help. really appreciate it. :)